# Remove duplicate values in a cell SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How do I remove duplicates in the following case in T-SQL?

I have a table with a column `Code` of type `varchar(max)`.

It contains a value like `A/A/B/C`. I need the cell value to be `A/B/C`.

Other possibility is `A/B/C/A` need to be `A/B/C`

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to normalize. You've got multiple values in the same column, and now you need constraints on the values.

Comment: How many different possible values could there be? Are they just characters or can they be longer strings with spaces?

Comment: There is no max possible but i would say it wound go beyond 10 (may be). It's not characters but strings and you are right, it can have spaces

Comment: Any column in a relational database should ***never*** contain multiple values to begin with! This is a violation of even the **first normal form**

Comment: is this table has only one column?

Comment: it's a business requirement to have this type of value in the column. The tables has more than one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION STR_Func (@Str AS VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(Max)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @count   INT,
              @tempstr VARCHAR(100)='',
              @nLength INT,
              @outstr  VARCHAR(100)=''

      SET @count=1
      SET @Str = Replace(@Str, '/', '')
      SET @nlength = Len(@Str)

      WHILE ( @count < @nLength )
        BEGIN
            SET @tempstr=@tempstr + Substring(@Str, 1, 1)
            SET @Str=Replace(@Str, Substring(@Str, 1, 1), '')
            SELECT @outstr = @outstr + RIGHT(@tempstr, 1) + '/'
            SET @count=@count + 1
        END

      RETURN LEFT(@outstr, Len(@outstr) - 1)
  END 

select dbo.STR_Func('B/A/C/A')
```

**OUTPUT :** `B/A/C`

If you want to remove duplicates and if dont care about the order then try this.

```
DECLARE @code  VARCHAR(100)='B/A/C/A',
        @code1 VARCHAR(100)=''


SELECT @code1 += '/' + splitrow
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') splitrow
        FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@code, '/', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
               CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) b

SELECT RIGHT(@code1, Len(@code1) - 1)
```

**OUTPUT** : `A/B/C`

Comment: Hi pradeep, A/B/A/C is just an example i gave, but A is a string and not a char

Comment: @Karthick Did u try my second method

Comment: it works thanks ! But could you explain your code? what is Split.a.value and Data.nodes . Thanks

Comment: @Karthick Converting the code data into `rows` using the delimiter `'/'` in the inner query. Then from that am taking the `distinct` values to remove duplicate and finally converting the rows to single value with delimiter `'/'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the blow code from this linke [SQL SERVER – Remove Duplicate Entry from Comma Delimited String]http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/15/sql-server-remove-duplicate-entry-from-comma-delimited-string-udf/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DistinctList
(
    @List VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delim CHAR
)
RETURNS
    VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ParsedList TABLE
    (
    Item VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    DECLARE @list1 VARCHAR(MAX), @Pos INT, @rList VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @list = LTRIM(RTRIM(@list)) + @Delim
    SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list, 1)
    WHILE @pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @list1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@list, @pos - 1)))
        IF @list1 <> ''
        INSERT INTO @ParsedList VALUES (CAST(@list1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
        SET @list = SUBSTRING(@list, @pos+1, LEN(@list))
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list, 1)
    END
    SELECT @rlist = COALESCE(@rlist+@Delim,'') + item
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM @ParsedList) t
    RETURN @rlist
END
GO
```

I changed the `SELECT @rlist = COALESCE(@rlist+',','') + item` to `SELECT @rlist = COALESCE(@rlist+@Delim,'') + item` because the original code is returning string with comma.

How to use:

```
SELECT dbo.DistinctList('A/B/C/A/A/A','/') DistinctList
```